# How to separate data from post meta - Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I will display post meta data with key 'jobfeature_zarobki'. This meta return following values:

```
jobfeature_zarobki : s:59:"a:2:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Zarobki";s:5:"value";s:8:"4800 zł";}";
```

I will display only '4800 zł'. How can I separate it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_post_meta` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ to access post meta.

Comment: I know, but it gives "jobfeature_zarobki : s:59:"a:2:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Zarobki";s:5:"value";s:8:"4800 zł";}";" I need only this "4800 zł" value. 

$key = 'jobfeature_zarobki';
$myvals = get_post_meta($postid);
    foreach($myvals as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key . ' : ' . $val[0] . '<br/>';
}

Comment: That is mean that you store value like that. It's serialized array, use `unserialize` http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php but it's not safe if this value passed from user (read note in function description) and also it may affect to speed performance.